# How do I remove HTML from MS Word 2010 document with Find/Replace Wildcards/Regex?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, regex, find-and-replace

I found a website to help me choose domain names. I have my shortlist which I can't export, but I need to share the list with some other team members first. It also won't let me copy and paste the list of domains.

With my limited knowledge, I clicked on inspect element, edit as HTML, copy and paste into MS Word 2010. Then I am left with a bunch of HTML looking like this:

```
<div id="cartList">
<div id="cartdomain_mydomain1.com" class="wordDiv">
    <img class="deleteImage" src="/images/trans.gif">
    <button class="buyButton">Buy</button>
    <div title="mydomain1.com">mydomain1.com</div>
</div>
<div id="cartdomain_mydomain2.com" class="wordDiv">
    <img class="deleteImage" src="/images/trans.gif">
    <button class="buyButton">Buy</button>
    <div title="mydomain2.com">mydomain2.com</div>
</div>
```

How do I remove all the HTML code so I am only left with mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com in a plain text list?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question isn't bad; it just needs to be improved. Please take a minute to read [ask], then [edit] your question to include appropriate details of what you've attempted on your own.

Comment: Well, I've pressed ctrl+h, and tried to play around with it but I realised I know nothing about regex and was hoping someone else could help me with the proper syntax?

Comment: Next time use more appropriate tools, allowing full regexp: Notepad++ or Ms Expression Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to have the "**More >>**" panel unfolded, and to select "**Use wildcards**". You can then use this expression:

**Find what**: `\<div id="cartdomain?*\<div title="([!"]*)"?*\</div\>?*\</div\>`

**Replace with**: `\1`

When clicking "Replace all", you will be left with your first line (`<div id="cartList">`) followed by everything that is in the "title" parameter.

MS2010 doesn't use the standard regex syntax, and is very limited. The way the expression works is:

- `<` and `>` are special delimiters, they have to be escaped with `\`
- `?*` is basically the equivalent of `.*?`: it matches any number of any character, non-greedily
- the parenthesis are used to define a capturing block, which is referred as `\1` in the `With:` field
- `[!"]*` means "any number of any character which is not a double quote"

Comment: Oh wait, had forgotten to click on "use wildcards" - works great, thank you.

Comment: @user325124 Ah, forgot this detail :D If it worked, you can (upvote and) validate the answer!